# Are multiple imagePullSecrets allowed and used by Kubernetes to pull an image from a private registry?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

I have a private registry (gitlab) where my docker images are stored.
For deployment a secret is created that allows GKE to access the registry. The secret is called `deploy-secret`. 
The secret's login information expires after short time in the registry.

I additionally created a second, permanent secret that allows access to the docker registry, named `permanent-secret`.

Is it possible to specify the Pod with two secrets? For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: deploy-secret
  - name: permanent-secret
```

Will Kubernetes, when trying to re-pull the image later, recognize that the first secret does not work (does not allow authentication to the private registry) and then fallback successfully to the second secret?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Surprisingly this works! I just tried this on my cluster. I added a fake registry credentials secret, with the wrong values. I put both secrets in my yaml like you did (below) and the pods got created and container is created and running successfully:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
      containers:
      - image: gitlab.myapp.com/my-image:tag
        name: test
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred-test
      - name: regcred
```

The `regcred` secret has the correct values and the `regcred-test` is just a bunch of gibberish. So we can see that it ignores the incorrect secret.

Comment: Could dockerconfigjson has multiple auths?

Comment: @zx1986 yes, it can.